# presto fetch data

Tags: python, sql, cursor, fetchall, presto

I have a result like this from presto command:

```
  a| b| c  
 --+--+------
 1 | 3| 6 
 2 | 4| 5
```

I know of `cursor.fetchall()` for all the data and `cursor.fetchone()` for a single row.

Now, I would like to get all the data from a particular column e.g. a `[1, 2]`

Is there a way to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw something and modified it to solve the problem

```
class reg(object):
 def __init__(self, cursor, row):
    for (attr, val) in zip((d[0] for d in cursor.description), row) :
        setattr(self, attr, val)
```

and have a loop to get the columns

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  r = reg(cursor, row)
  print r.a
```